Conditional creation/updation of a for_each resource based on a list in .tfvars
We have various terraform resources under module and there are 30+ tenants already created via for_each loop. Whenever we execute terraform all the tenant resources are getting executed during any tenant onboarding, or during any tenant specific update requested.
../modules/
├── function_app
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── monitoring_telemetry
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── storage_account
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── storage_containers
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── telemetry
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── tenants
    ├── main.tf
    ├── output.tf
    ├── provider.tf
    └── variables.tf

tfvars:
existing_tenants="alpha,beta"
new_tenants="gamma"
tenant = { 

  "alpha" = {
    "name" = "alpha"
  },
  "beta" = {
    "name" = "beta"
  },
  "gamma" = {
    "name" = "gamma"
  }

}

Expectation:
Expectation is to create resources only for **gamma ** tenant. Here we are managing single state file per environment, it would be difficult to move 30+ tenants into individual state files now.
we had tried:
Dynamic ignore lifecycle ignore_changes = contains(local.existing_tenants_list, each.key) ? "[tags]" : "[all]" even with ignore_changes = local.ignore_changes_static[each.key]
ERROR: only static variable reference is required
resource "example_resource" "tenants" {
for_each = { for tenant in var.tenant : tenant => tenant if !contains(var.existing_tenants, tenant) }
.
.
.
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
}
}

ERROR:  lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the plan calls for this
resource to be destroyed. Existing Tenants are trying to be destroyed
resource "example_resource" "tenants" {
for_each = var.tenant
count    = contains(var.new_tenants, each.key) ? 1 : 0
}

ERROR: can't use count and for_each together in same block
resource "example_resource" "new_tenants" {
for_each = var.new_tenants
}
resource "example_resource" "existing_tenants" {
for_each = var.existing_tenants
}

Facing issues with new/next executions, as new_tenants becomes existing_tenants in next executions
I understand that terraform's purpose may not be meant for the same.

I'm not sure I understand why is there a need to differentiate between the new and old tenants. Using for_each will take care of that anyway.


Conditional creation/updation of a for_each resource based on a list in .tfvars

Thanks @Marko for highlighting the point in right direction by using all tenants in one roof by declaring as local.tenants and introduce them as locals. Rest of the steps taken care by itself.
In the configuration you shared you mentioned the tenants as existing_tenants and new_tenants with the combination as lifecycle.ignore_changes = contains(...) which in general does not work.
You can check as per the SO link with the error mentioned that static variable reference is required but the lifecycle you mentioned is dynamic & using count and foreach in the single module is also not possible using terraform.
lifecycle should be as mentioned below.
locals { tenants = merge(var.existing_tenants, var.new_tenants) }
.
.
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  name                     = "${each.key}storageaccount"
 .
 .
 . 
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = var.is_new_tenant ? [] : [tags, account_replication_type]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function" {
  name                = "${each.key}-function-app"
  .
  ,

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = !var.is_new_tenant
  }
}

terraform.tfvars:
existing_tenants = {
  "alpha" = {
    name = "alpha"
  },
  "beta" = {
    name = "beta"
  }
}

new_tenants = {
  "gamma" = {
    name = "gamma"
  }
}

tags = {
  environment = "production"
}

make changes with the way you use for_each & count in modules and also referring your tenants' locally.
Refer:
The for_each Meta-Argument - Configuration Language | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer
The count Meta-Argument - Configuration Language | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer
The lifecycle Meta-Argument - Configuration Language | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer
build a dynamic ignore_changes in terraform - Stack Overflow answered by Marko E
